# Unit test "No Symbol loaded" is driving me crazy

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, debugging, uwp

When I'm unit testing in VS2017, if I mistakenly press F11 while on method calling something that I DONT want to step in, it will step inside and I get this painful and irritating message.

[image]

> WinTypes.pdb contains the debug information required to find the source for the module WinTypes.dll

This happens when I have call to windows runtime libraries or framework libraries. I DONT want to step inside these libraries. and no matter how many times I press F10 again or close this page, this message wont let me continue .

All I have to do is to reset debug process and start from over again... I was bearing with this for a while but ive had enough. this is driving me CRAZY. please show me way how to stop this stupid error.

.Net framework source stepping is also unchecked, but I'm unit testing UWP project.

[image]

PS: Just my code is also enabled FFS -.-

Comment: Was this "WinTypes.dll" is your own library? You'd better check if there're some exception messages in it when you're debugging.

Comment: @M.kazem Akhgary, Could you debug your app after you enable Microsoft symbol Servers?

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure the WinTypes.pdb has been loaded first. You could add a breakpoint in your code where before this issue occurs. And then open Debug -> Windows -> Modules. It will list the statues of all dlls that in your project. If the pdb file for WinTypes.dll is skipped, which is similar with below screenshot, you could right-click on it to choose "Load Symbols".
[image]

If load failed after choose "Load Symbols", please check the Symbol Source from Tools menu -> Options -> Debugging -> Symbols to make sure the Microsoft Symbol Servers has been checked.
[image]